# Automatic Update of IPhone App

Tags: iphone, database

I am new to iPhone automatic updatability feature where user can change their contents whenever they want and iPhone app should pick them so that one need not to resubmit the application into Apple store. I know that I will need to deal with the database here a lot but if someone could through their idea on the solution design, implementation, and things to be taken care then that would be really helpful to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple not only allows this, but presented a session on this data driven app design technique at WWDC 2010, which is available as a video from iTunes to enrolled iOS developers.

Of course, the downloaded "content" can't include executable code, but it can include JavaScript and HTML5 to be run inside UIWebViews, as well as images, sounds, text, databases, etc., which can all be stored for offline use.

Comment: wow Hotpaw2, that's exactly I am looking for. If you could point me out some sample Apps that does change the images, sounds contents etc then it would be really great..

Comment: Hi Hotpaw2, I am enrolled iOS developer but I couldn't find a session on this data driven app design technique at WWDC 2010. Could you please point me a link please.

Answer (score 1):

"content" here really means data. Apps can load data over the net to their hearts' content, but they can't load new code. Now, certain data might cause the existing code in the app to do one thing or another, so the app's behavior can be influenced by the data it uses. Don't play too close to the line, though -- if your data is really some form of scripting language that directly drives the behavior of the app, that will likely be deemed unacceptable.

As far as loading the content goes, there are a number of options available. The most common is probably using NSURLConnection asynchronously to load data from a web server. What the app does with the data after that is up to the app designer, and I don't think there's one objectively correct answer to that sort of question.

Answer (score 0):

This violates apples SDK Agreement and will likely get your app removed from the app store if caught.

Comment: It really depends on what's meant by "change their contents," doesn't it? Many apps wouldn't be at all useful if they didn't change their content on a regular basis. You cross a line at some point, though, when "data" are interpreted as "instructions" that implement features, capabilities, etc. I think the "I'll know it when I see it" rule applies here.

Comment: Hi Chris, we are not going to generate any code off course. While testing, its simple for us as we have frontend website that can send the updated resources and XML file to iPhone app installed on my development iPhone. We have functionality such that on shake event, it pops the menu where we can Refresh the app and fetch the resources from site. For our main requirements, I have given house properties App example in my previous comment above.

Answer (score 0):

It should be mentioned that web apps offer the ultimate in automatic content updates. You can change the content, structure, and features of a web app without ever having to submit your app to Apple or anyone else. Deploying the app is as simple as copying a set of files to your server, and users get the updated version immediately, even if they're currently using the app. Web apps aren't a perfect solution in every case, but their capabilites are compelling if your app is dynamic.

Comment: I presume that web apps would not be available in AppStore. Our customers first requirement is to push app in AppStore. The basic idea is to avoid the resubmitting the application off course with meeting the Apple's guideline. For example, we have customer that has house properties App. We provide a frontend to add the new houses whenever available and get rid of already sold house.  Now the problem is whenever he wants to do so, we have to resubmit the application which takes approximately a week to approve and customer doesn't want to wait that long. I hope that makes much clear specs.

Comment: Clearly, the information regarding the particular houses for sale should be loaded over the network and not built into the app. This is very common practice, and there are many, many examples. You might start with Apple's "SeismicXML" sample project.